# Extracting information from two lines simultaneously in Python

Tags: python, loops

I have a file with lines of SAMfields, containing information and DNA sequences in different Tab-delimited fields. Each line is a unique sample, but every two lines are coupled (paired) and so I would like to extract information from two lines simultaneously.

While I can easily extract information from these fields line by line, I would like to have a way to analyze both lines simultaneously. Is there a loop (or way to manipulate a loop through line by line) to get this done?

Comment: Could elaborate your question a bit more please? Perhaps provide some data and examples?

Answer (score 4):

You can use itertools to do what you want.More specifically [izip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip). I presume it would benefit you since it's memory friendly and you mine DNA data.

```
import itertools

with open(file) as f:
   for l,j in itertools.izip(f,f):
       print l,j
```

Comment: This doesn't handle breaking the file input by line

Comment: @theorifice can you be more specific? In a test file i get 2 lines in each iteration, what the op is asking.

Comment: Forget that. I didn't realize that iterating over a file object yields lines! That's news to me. Sorry about that.

Comment: @theorifice yes don't you just love python?

Comment: @Martijn No problem. If you decide to go with it and no other answers appear consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can zip all the even-numbered rows with all the odd-numbered rows. So, you can do:

```
with open(myFile) as inputFile:
    for sequence in zip(inputFile[::2], inputFile[1::2]):
        print(sequence)  # prints lines 0,1 then lines 2,3 etc.
```

Comment: not saying it is incorrect, just that as an answer it seems lacking any explanation

Comment: Added some explanation.

Comment: It *is* incorrect, file objects are nor subscriptable.

Answer (score 0):

A more flexible way of doing this would be to use a generator:

```
def line_pairs(file):
    file_iter = iter(file)
    while True:
        line1 = next(file_iter)
        line2 = next(file_iter)
        yield (line1, line2)

for line1, line2 in line_pairs(file):
    # do what you want with line1 and line2 available at the same time
```

Now if you realize you need to handle some lines specially (e.g. strip blank lines) you can just modify the generator.